# Get the name of the file that contains a string

Tags: php, regex, file, file-get-contents

I'd like to get the filename of the file that contains a string (within a specific folder).

**For example:** There's a folder called "test". In this folder there a three files, but only one of them contains the string "hello". Now I'd like to get back the name of this file with PHP.

(all files are .txt)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well you'll have to open and read all files..

Comment: Ouch. This is going to be a computationally expensive thing to do in PHP.

Comment: this via console : grep -nr "your string 123456" Folder , tells you which line is located, and also in that file

Comment: just [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) the folder, take the files, do a _strpos_ in them, return filename on success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get all file names in the folder for the given extension.
2. Read contents of all files sequentially.
3. Read each line of each file and look for words matching "hello world"
4. Save file name containing matches in an array.

Haven't tested it, but something like the following should work:

```
$data = glob(FOLDER . "*.txt");

// filter
$filter = array();

// read contents of all files
for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++) {
    $file_path = $data[$i];

    // open file in read-only mode
    $fp = fopen( $file, 'r' );

    // read file data
    $file_data = fread($fp, filesize($file_path));

    // close file handle
    fclose($fp);

    // make sure we catch CR-only line endings.
    $file_data = str_replace("\r", "\n", $file_data);

    // match using regexp
    if(preg_match('/(hello world)/im', $file_data)) {
        $file_name = basename($data[$i]);
        array_push($filter, $file_name);
    }
}

// output filtered file names
echo nl2br(print_r($filter, TRUE));
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Scan the folder.
2. Open each file / read the contents.
3. Use the function [stristr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) to check if the string "hello" exists.

Comment: Now you are opening each file... This takes a long time in PHP

Comment: at least this is a real cross platform solution

Comment: @RichardBernards Three text files shouldn't take too long to open.

Answer (score 3):

**Assuming a *nix environment**

The following will produce a `$output` variable containing an array with the filenames:

```
$output = exec("grep -l 'hello' test/*.txt");
```

Comment: you're assuming that he's using a *nix environment..

Comment: As long as exec() is available, this is a good solution.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon I have updated my answer with your useful comment

Comment: this for search multiple string : grep -nr "your string 123456" Folder , in all file and in all sub-directory